# Add HTML elements before a specific tag for jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following

```
// jQuery
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));//.prev().hide().show("slow");
}

// HTML
<ul class="sortable_fields">
</ul>
<p id="add_field"><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Trip Day", f, :trip_days %></p>
```

I am using Rails, you can gracefully ignore it. When I add a field, the new HTML code as depicted in `content.replace(regexp, new_id)` will show after `<p>`. For example:

If `content.replace(regexp, new_id)` is `<li>Test</li>`, it will result:

```
<ul class="sortable_fields">
</ul>
<p id="add_field"><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Trip Day", f, :trip_days %></p>
<li>Test</li>
```

instead of:

```
<ul class="sortable_fields">
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
<p id="add_field"><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Trip Day", f, :trip_days %></p>
```

I know I could change the `.before()`, but since there are HTML contents which will be generated by the system, I rather not touch it. How should I change the jQuery?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just append the elements inside of `ul.sortable_fields`?

Comment: @JoshLeitzel If I put `<p>` inside `<ul>`, there will be sortable problem, which means the `<p>` is also sortable. E.g. new `<li>` can be sorted below `<p>`.

Comment: No, I mean put the `<li`> into `<ul>`...

Comment: @JoshLeitzel Can share your answer?

Comment: Done. I just wanted to make sure I understood what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get from 'a' to 'ul'

```
$(link).parent().prev().append(  newContent )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look for the `ul` directly -- it's much less fragile than relying on the DOM relationships that you're relying on:

```
$(link).closest('ul.sortable_fields').append(content.replace(regexp, new_id))
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have tried yours, but doesn't work. There's no error showing in Firebug, but charlietfl's works, I guess I should move on. But I appreciate your help very much. Thanks.